# Oracle APEX downloaded text file opens in current window

Tags: oracle-apex

Oracle DB 12.1, APEX 5

I have a button to call PL/SQL process. Process calls REST, converts response (json) to BLOB and uses traditional `download_my_file`-like procedure to present result to user, but instead of "download/open" browser question file content just showns as text, replacing current APEX page.

How can I download it as file when click on button instead open in current window?

Process:

```
...
l_envelope := APEX_WEB_SERVICE.make_rest_request(...);
...
apex_clob2file ('text.txt', l_envelope, 'application/json');
```

Procedure

```
create or replace PROCEDURE apex_clob2file (in_filename IN VARCHAR2, in_data IN CLOB, in_mime IN VARCHAR2)
IS
...
BEGIN
...
  htp.init;
  owa_util.mime_header(nvl(in_mime, 'text/plain'), FALSE);
  htp.p('Content-Length: ' || dbms_lob.getlength(l_blob));
  htp.p('Content-Disposition: filename="' || in_filename || '"');
  owa_util.http_header_close;
  wpg_docload.download_file(l_blob);
  apex_application.stop_apex_engine;
...
END apex_clob2file;
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything I have to do is **attachment** option:

```
htp.p('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=...
```